# How do I convert a .jar file to a Unix executable file? (Mac)

Tags: java, macos, unix, compilation, javac

I have created a java project, and I have exported it to my desktop.

Is there a way of converting that .jar file on my desktop, to a Unix executable file?

Comment: Java is available on many platforms - simply install java on the desired platform and `java -jar myjar.jar`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already know that terminal command, but I would like to know how to convert that .jar file, to a Unix executable file.

Comment: Perhaps explaining a bit more on why? in your post might elicit more responses - that's all I can add - good luck.

Comment: If you use Java 14 check out [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html).

Comment: What properties do you need?  It is trivially simple to write a launcher script.

Comment: I am writing a very simple interpreter for a programming language that I designed, called 'Candle'. Ideally, I would like to have the final program as a Unix executable which, if I am write in saying, is a .exec extension. I would like to be able to type the command 'candle <file name>.can' into the terminal, and then it would interpret and run that Candle file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a launch file (shortcut). 
You need to create a file with text:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar myProject.jar
```

and make it executable:

```
chmod + x ./shortcutfile
```

OR

Right click on jar-file. Select "Open With Other Application" and choose "Runtime Environment".

Comment: I will try that. Thanks. I don't seem to have the Runtime Enrionment option for some reason. Any idea why not?